# Watch Face Settings Select Background Image

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

Situation:

I want to have a Watch-Face with a specific background.
The user should be able to change the background from a pool of 8 images that I define.

Problem:

The WearableListenerService and it's components give me a headache and I have no idea what I am doing. I tried to study the code but couldn't get the relations of the code. I then tried to use the code that Google defined in their demo but it does not work correctly in the way that the WatchFace background does not change.

What I already tried:

As I already mentioned, I tried to use Googles Code. I also searched for tutorials in the internet but they couldn't help me either. I added my current code below.

I really don't want to seem like a lazy person waiting for someone to write my code. I really tried but I can't get it to work.

---

Watch Face

```
package net.premadegames.gravityfaces;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceStyle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.WindowInsets;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class GravityFace extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
    private static final String TAG = "DigitalWatchFaceService";

    private static final Typeface NORMAL_TYPEFACE =
            Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);

    private static final long INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

    private static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new Engine();
    }

    private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine implements DataApi.DataListener,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new EngineHandler(this);

        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(GravityFace.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

        int faceID = DigitalWatchFaceUtil.DEFAULT_FACEID;

        final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mTime.clear(intent.getStringExtra("time-zone"));
                mTime.setToNow();
            }
        };
        boolean mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;

        Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;
        Bitmap mBackgroundBitmap;
        Bitmap mBackgroundScaledBitmap;
        Paint mTextPaint;

        Resources resources;

        boolean mAmbient;
        Time mTime;

        boolean mLowBitAmbient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onCreate(holder);

            setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(GravityFace.this)
                    .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_VARIABLE)
                    .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                    .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                    .build());
            resources = GravityFace.this.getResources();

            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face1);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();

            mTextPaint = new Paint();
            mTextPaint = createTextPaint(resources.getColor(R.color.digital_text));
            mTextPaint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2f, Color.argb(60, 0, 0, 0));

            mTime = new Time();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private Paint createTextPaint(int textColor) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(textColor);
            paint.setTypeface(NORMAL_TYPEFACE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            return paint;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

            if (visible) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                registerReceiver();

                // Update time zone in case it changed while we weren't visible.
                mTime.clear(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                mTime.setToNow();
            } else {
                unregisterReceiver();

                if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Wearable.DataApi.removeListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            }

            updateTimer();
        }

        private void registerReceiver() {
            if (mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
                return;
            }
            mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
            GravityFace.this.registerReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver, filter);
        }

        private void unregisterReceiver() {
            if (!mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
                return;
            }
            mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;
            GravityFace.this.unregisterReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver);
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
            super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

            // Load resources that have alternate values for round watches.
            Resources resources = GravityFace.this.getResources();
            boolean isRound = insets.isRound();
            float textSize = resources.getDimension(isRound
                    ? R.dimen.digital_text_size_round : R.dimen.digital_text_size);

            mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
            super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
            mLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeTick() {
            super.onTimeTick();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
            super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
            if (mAmbient != inAmbientMode) {
                mAmbient = inAmbientMode;
                if (mLowBitAmbient) {
                    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(!inAmbientMode);
                }
                invalidate();
            }

            // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
            // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
            updateTimer();
        }

        private void updateBackgroundIfInteractive(int faceID) {
            if (!isInAmbientMode()) {
                if(faceID == 1) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face1);
                } else if(faceID == 2) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face2);
                } else if(faceID == 3) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face3);
                } else if(faceID == 4) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face4);
                } else if(faceID == 5) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face5);
                } else if(faceID == 6) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face6);
                } else if(faceID == 7) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face7);
                } else if(faceID == 8) {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face8);
                } else {
                    mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face1);
                }

                mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            }
        }

        private void setInteractiveFaceBackground(int faceID) {
            updateBackgroundIfInteractive(faceID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {

            // Draw the background.
            if (isInAmbientMode()) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                if (mBackgroundScaledBitmap == null || mBackgroundScaledBitmap.getWidth() != canvas.getWidth() || mBackgroundScaledBitmap.getHeight() != canvas.getHeight()) {
                    mBackgroundScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true /* filter */);
                }
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundScaledBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            }

            // Draw H:MM in ambient mode or H:MM:SS in interactive mode.
            mTime.setToNow();
            String text = String.format("%d:%02d", mTime.hour, mTime.minute);

            int width = bounds.width();
            int height = bounds.height();

            float centerX = width / 2f;
            float centerY = height / 2f;

            Rect boundsText = new Rect();
            mTextPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), boundsText);

            int text_height = boundsText.height();
            int text_width = boundsText.width();

            canvas.drawText(text, centerX - text_width / 2, centerY + text_height / 2, mTextPaint);
        }

        /**
         * Starts the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer if it should be running and isn't currently
         * or stops it if it shouldn't be running but currently is.
         */
        private void updateTimer() {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer should be running. The timer should
         * only run when we're visible and in interactive mode.
         */
        private boolean shouldTimerBeRunning() {
            return isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode();
        }

        private void updateConfigDataItemAndUiOnStartup() {
            DigitalWatchFaceUtil.fetchConfigDataMap(mGoogleApiClient,
                    new DigitalWatchFaceUtil.FetchConfigDataMapCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigDataMapFetched(DataMap startupConfig) {
                            // If the DataItem hasn't been created yet or some keys are missing,
                            // use the default values.
                            setDefaultValuesForMissingConfigKeys(startupConfig);
                            DigitalWatchFaceUtil.putConfigDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, startupConfig);

                            updateUiForConfigDataMap(startupConfig);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }

        private void setDefaultValuesForMissingConfigKeys(DataMap config) {
            addIntKeyIfMissing(config, DigitalWatchFaceUtil.KEY_FACEID,
                    DigitalWatchFaceUtil.DEFAULT_FACEID);
        }

        private void addIntKeyIfMissing(DataMap config, String key, int color) {
            if (!config.containsKey(key)) {
                config.putInt(key, color);
            }
        }

        @Override // DataApi.DataListener
        public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
            for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEvents) {
                if (dataEvent.getType() != DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                    continue;
                }

                DataItem dataItem = dataEvent.getDataItem();
                if (!dataItem.getUri().getPath().equals(
                        DigitalWatchFaceUtil.PATH_WITH_FEATURE)) {
                    continue;
                }

                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem);
                DataMap config = dataMapItem.getDataMap();
                if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Config DataItem updated:" + config);
                }
                updateUiForConfigDataMap(config);
            }
        }

        private void updateUiForConfigDataMap(final DataMap config) {
            boolean uiUpdated = false;
            for (String configKey : config.keySet()) {
                if (!config.containsKey(configKey)) {
                    continue;
                }
                int color = config.getInt(configKey);
                if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Found watch face config key: " + configKey + " -> "
                            + Integer.toHexString(color));
                }
                if (updateUiForKey(faceID)) {
                    uiUpdated = true;
                }
            }
            if (uiUpdated) {
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Updates the color of a UI item according to the given {@code configKey}. Does nothing if
         * {@code configKey} isn't recognized.
         *
         * @return whether UI has been updated
         */
        private boolean updateUiForKey(int faceID) {
            setInteractiveFaceBackground(faceID);
            return true;
        }

        @Override  // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
            }
            Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, Engine.this);
            updateConfigDataItemAndUiOnStartup();
        }

        @Override  // GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
            }
        }

        @Override  // GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Handle updating the time periodically in interactive mode.
         */
        private void handleUpdateTimeMessage() {
            invalidate();
            if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long delayMs = INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS
                        - (timeMs % INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS);
                mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, delayMs);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class EngineHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<GravityFace.Engine> mWeakReference;

        public EngineHandler(GravityFace.Engine reference) {
            mWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(reference);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            GravityFace.Engine engine = mWeakReference.get();
            if (engine != null) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_UPDATE_TIME:
                        engine.handleUpdateTimeMessage();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Settings Activity

```
package net.premadegames.gravityfaces;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.Random;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DigitalWatchFaceConfig";

    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button mButton;

    Random r = new Random();

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
                mButton = (Button) stub.findViewById(R.id.button);

                mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int i1 = r.nextInt(7)+1;

                        updateConfigDataItem(i1);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void updateConfigDataItem(final int faceID) {
        DataMap configKeysToOverwrite = new DataMap();
        configKeysToOverwrite.putInt(DigitalWatchFaceUtil.KEY_FACEID, faceID);
        DigitalWatchFaceUtil.overwriteKeysInConfigDataMap(mGoogleApiClient, configKeysToOverwrite);
    }
}
```

Digital Watch Face Util

```
package net.premadegames.gravityfaces;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMapItem;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public final class DigitalWatchFaceUtil {
    private static final String TAG = "DigitalWatchFaceUtil";

    /**
     * The {@link DataMap} key for {@link DigitalWatchFaceService} background color name.
     * The color name must be a {@link String} recognized by {@link Color#parseColor}.
     */
    public static final String KEY_FACEID = "FACEID";


    /**
     * The path for the {@link DataItem} containing {@link DigitalWatchFaceService} configuration.
     */
    public static final String PATH_WITH_FEATURE = "/watch_face_config";

    /**
     * Name of the default interactive mode background color and the ambient mode background color.
     */
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_FACEID = 1;
    /**
     * Callback interface to perform an action with the current config {@link DataMap} for
     * {@link DigitalWatchFaceService}.
     */
    public interface FetchConfigDataMapCallback {
        /**
         * Callback invoked with the current config {@link DataMap} for
         * {@link DigitalWatchFaceService}.
         */
        void onConfigDataMapFetched(DataMap config);
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronously fetches the current config {@link DataMap} for {@link DigitalWatchFaceService}
     * and passes it to the given callback.
     * <p>
     * If the current config {@link DataItem} doesn't exist, it isn't created and the callback
     * receives an empty DataMap.
     */
    public static void fetchConfigDataMap(final GoogleApiClient client,
                                          final FetchConfigDataMapCallback callback) {
        Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(client).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult getLocalNodeResult) {
                        String localNode = getLocalNodeResult.getNode().getId();
                        Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                                .scheme("wear")
                                .path(DigitalWatchFaceUtil.PATH_WITH_FEATURE)
                                .authority(localNode)
                                .build();
                        Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(client, uri)
                                .setResultCallback(new DataItemResultCallback(callback));
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Overwrites (or sets, if not present) the keys in the current config {@link DataItem} with
     * the ones appearing in the given {@link DataMap}. If the config DataItem doesn't exist,
     * it's created.
     * <p>
     * It is allowed that only some of the keys used in the config DataItem appear in
     * {@code configKeysToOverwrite}. The rest of the keys remains unmodified in this case.
     */
    public static void overwriteKeysInConfigDataMap(final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                                    final DataMap configKeysToOverwrite) {

        DigitalWatchFaceUtil.fetchConfigDataMap(googleApiClient,
                new FetchConfigDataMapCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigDataMapFetched(DataMap currentConfig) {
                        DataMap overwrittenConfig = new DataMap();
                        overwrittenConfig.putAll(currentConfig);
                        overwrittenConfig.putAll(configKeysToOverwrite);
                        DigitalWatchFaceUtil.putConfigDataItem(googleApiClient, overwrittenConfig);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Overwrites the current config {@link DataItem}'s {@link DataMap} with {@code newConfig}.
     * If the config DataItem doesn't exist, it's created.
     */
    public static void putConfigDataItem(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, DataMap newConfig) {
        PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(PATH_WITH_FEATURE);
        DataMap configToPut = putDataMapRequest.getDataMap();
        configToPut.putAll(newConfig);
        Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest())
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "putDataItem result status: " + dataItemResult.getStatus());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private static class DataItemResultCallback implements ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult> {

        private final FetchConfigDataMapCallback mCallback;

        public DataItemResultCallback(FetchConfigDataMapCallback callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                if (dataItemResult.getDataItem() != null) {
                    DataItem configDataItem = dataItemResult.getDataItem();
                    DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(configDataItem);
                    DataMap config = dataMapItem.getDataMap();
                    mCallback.onConfigDataMapFetched(config);
                } else {
                    mCallback.onConfigDataMapFetched(new DataMap());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private DigitalWatchFaceUtil() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the user should be able to change, then try below logic.

```
/*Change background when user taps on the watchface*/

private int mTapCount=0;

@Override
public void onTapCommand (int tapType, int x, int y, long eventTime){
    if (tapType == WatchFaceService.TAP_TYPE_TAP)
        changeBackground();
    invalidate();
}

private void changeBackground() {
    mTapCount++;
    switch(mTapCount % 8) {
        Case 0:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face1);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 1:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face2);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 2:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face3);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 3:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face4);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 4:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face5);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 5:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face6);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 6:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face7);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
        Case 7:
            mBackgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face8);
            mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
            break;
    }
}
```